# Pthread: Increasing program execution time with respect to number of threads

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, pthreads

I am trying to build an efficient concurrent hash map using pthreads, C.

Following is my implementation

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET 3

struct Bucket
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    void **keys;
    int *vals;
    struct Bucket *next;
};

struct Concurrent_Map
{
    struct Bucket *buckets;
    map_keys_equality *keys_eq;
    map_key_hash *khash;
    int capacity;
};

int concurrent_map_allocate /*@ <t> @*/ (map_keys_equality *keq, map_key_hash *khash,
                                         unsigned capacity,
                                         struct Concurrent_Map **map_out)

{

    struct Concurrent_Map *old_map_val = *map_out;
    struct Concurrent_Map *map_alloc = malloc(sizeof(struct Concurrent_Map));
    if (map_alloc == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    *map_out = (struct Concurrent_Map *)map_alloc;

    struct Bucket *buckets_alloc = (struct Bucket *)malloc(sizeof(struct Bucket) * (int)capacity);

    if (buckets_alloc == NULL)
    {
        free(map_alloc);
        *map_out = old_map_val;
        return 0;
    }
    (*map_out)->buckets = buckets_alloc;
    (*map_out)->capacity = capacity;
    (*map_out)->keys_eq = keq;
    (*map_out)->khash = khash;

    unsigned i;

    for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_mutex_init(&((*map_out)->buckets[i].mutex), NULL) == 0)
        {
            void **key_alloc = malloc(sizeof(void *) * (ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET));

            if (key_alloc != NULL)
            {
                (*map_out)->buckets[i].keys = key_alloc;

                int k;
                for (k = 0; k < ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET; k++)
                {

                    (*map_out)->buckets[i].keys[k] = NULL;
                }
            }

            int *vals_alloc = malloc(sizeof(int) * (ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET));

            if (vals_alloc != NULL)
            {
                (*map_out)->buckets[i].vals = vals_alloc;

                int k;
                for (k = 0; k < ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET; k++)
                {
                    (*map_out)->buckets[i].vals[k] = -1;
                }
            }

            (*map_out)->buckets[i].next = NULL;
        }
    }

    // todo exceptions in allocation

    return 1;
}

static unsigned loop(unsigned k, unsigned capacity)
{
    unsigned g = k % capacity;

    unsigned res = (g + capacity) % capacity;

    return res;
}

int concurrent_map_get(struct Concurrent_Map *map, void *key, int *value_out)

{
    map_key_hash *khash = map->khash;
    unsigned hash = khash(key);

    unsigned start = loop(hash, map->capacity);
    unsigned bucket_index = loop(start + 0, map->capacity);

    if (bucket_index < map->capacity)
    {

        struct Bucket *bucket = &(map->buckets[bucket_index]);

        pthread_mutex_t mutex = bucket->mutex;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        int j;
        do
        {
            for (j = 0; j < ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET; j++)
            {
                int val = bucket->vals[j];
                if (map->keys_eq(bucket->keys[j], key))
                {
                    if (bucket->vals[j] == val)
                    {
                        *value_out = val;
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        *value_out = -1;
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (bucket->next != NULL)
            {
                bucket = (bucket->next);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            }

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        } while (1);
    }
    *value_out = -1;
    return 0;
}

int concurrent_map_put(struct Concurrent_Map *map, void *key, int value)

{
    map_key_hash *khash = map->khash;
    unsigned hash = khash(key);

    unsigned start = loop(hash, map->capacity);
    unsigned bucket_index = loop(start + 0, map->capacity);

    struct Bucket *bucket = &(map->buckets[bucket_index]);

    int j;

    do
    {

        pthread_mutex_t mutex = bucket->mutex;

        int j;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        for (j = 0; j < ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET; j++)
        {
            if (map->keys_eq(bucket->keys[j], key))
            {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                return 0;
            }
            else if (bucket->keys[j] == NULL)
            {
                bucket->vals[j] = value;
                bucket->keys[j] = key;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        if (bucket->next == NULL)

        {
            // allocate a new bucket

            struct Bucket *new_bucket = malloc(sizeof(struct Bucket));

            if (pthread_mutex_init(&(new_bucket->mutex), NULL) == 0)
            {
                void **key_alloc = malloc(sizeof(void *) * (ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET));

                if (key_alloc != NULL)
                {
                    new_bucket->keys = key_alloc;

                    int k;
                    for (k = 0; k < ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET; k++)
                    {
                        new_bucket->keys[k] = NULL;
                    }
                }

                int *vals_alloc = malloc(sizeof(int) * (ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET));

                if (vals_alloc != NULL)
                {
                    new_bucket->vals = vals_alloc;

                    int k;
                    for (k = 0; k < ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET; k++)
                    {
                        new_bucket->vals[k] = -1;
                    }
                }

                bucket->next = new_bucket;
            }
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        bucket = bucket->next;

    } while (1);

    return 0;
}

int concurrent_map_erase(struct Concurrent_Map *map, void *key, void **trash)

{

    map_key_hash *khash = map->khash;
    unsigned hash = khash(key);

    unsigned start = loop(hash, map->capacity);
    unsigned bucket_index = loop(start + 0, map->capacity);

    struct Bucket *bucket = &(map->buckets[bucket_index]);

    int j;

    do
    {

        pthread_mutex_t mutex = bucket->mutex;

        int j;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        for (j = 0; j < ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET; j++)
        {
            if (map->keys_eq(bucket->keys[j], key))
            {
                bucket->vals[j] = -1;
                bucket->keys[j] = NULL;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        if (bucket->next != NULL)
        {
            bucket = (bucket->next);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    } while (1);
    return 0;
}

int concurrent_map_size(struct Concurrent_Map *map)

{
    int num_buckets = 0;

    struct Bucket *buckets = map->buckets;
    unsigned i;

    for (i = 0; i < map->capacity; i++)
    {
        struct Bucket bucket = buckets[i];
        do
        {
            num_buckets++;
            if (bucket.next != NULL)
            {
                bucket = *(bucket.next);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        } while (1);
    }
    return num_buckets * ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET;
}
struct FlowId
{
    int src_port;
    int dst_port;
    int src_ip;
    int dst_ip;
    int internal_device;
    int protocol;
};

bool FlowId_eq(void *a, void *b)

{
    if (a == NULL || b == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    struct FlowId *id1 = a;
    struct FlowId *id2 = b;

    return (id1->src_port == id2->src_port) && (id1->dst_port == id2->dst_port) && (id1->src_ip == id2->src_ip) && (id1->dst_ip == id2->dst_ip) && (id1->internal_device == id2->internal_device) && (id1->protocol == id2->protocol);
}

unsigned FlowId_hash(void *obj)

{
    struct FlowId *id = obj;
    unsigned hash = 0;
    hash = __builtin_ia32_crc32si(hash, id->src_port);
    hash = __builtin_ia32_crc32si(hash, id->dst_port);
    hash = __builtin_ia32_crc32si(hash, id->src_ip);
    hash = __builtin_ia32_crc32si(hash, id->dst_ip);
    hash = __builtin_ia32_crc32si(hash, id->internal_device);
    hash = __builtin_ia32_crc32si(hash, id->protocol);
    return hash;
}

struct Concurrent_Map *concurrent_map;

#define NUM_THREADS 2
#define NUM_PACKETS 10000000

void *expirator(void *arg)
{
    // printf("Thread started executing\n");
    unsigned i = 0;
    int error = 0;
    unsigned packet_count = NUM_PACKETS / NUM_THREADS;
    while (i < packet_count)
    {
        i++;
        struct FlowId *id = malloc(sizeof(struct FlowId));
        struct FlowId *id1 = malloc(sizeof(struct FlowId));
        id->dst_ip = 1;
        id->src_ip = 1;
        id->internal_device = 1;
        id->protocol = 1;
        id->src_port = 1;
        id->dst_port = rand() % 65536;

        id1->dst_ip = 1;
        id1->src_ip = 1;
        id1->internal_device = 1;
        id1->protocol = 1;
        id1->src_port = 1;
        id1->dst_port = rand() % 65536;

        int external_port = rand() % 65536;
        int external;

        concurrent_map_erase(concurrent_map, id, NULL);

        concurrent_map_put(concurrent_map, id, external_port);
        concurrent_map_get(concurrent_map, id, &external);

        if (external_port != external)
        {
            error++;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{

    clock_t begin = clock();

    concurrent_map_allocate(FlowId_eq, FlowId_hash, 65536, &(concurrent_map));

    pthread_t *threads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * NUM_THREADS);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, expirator, NULL) != 0)
        {
            printf("Error creating threads");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL) != 0)
        {
            printf("Error joining threads");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%lf\n", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is how to run this program.

```
gcc  concurrent_map.c  -o test-concurrent-new -lpthread -msse4.2 -O3
```

Then I measure the execution time for a fixed workload and following are the time values I observed.

1: 3.29

2: 6.687811

3: 5.88

4: 6.23

5: 6.38

6: 6.52

7: 6.74

8: 6.82

It seems that when the number of threads is increased the execution time increases and remains almost same.

I profiled this code using Mutrace, which looks for mutex contention. It turns out that

> No mutex contended according to filtering parameters.

I checked the number of cache misses, and it turned out that number of cache misses are roughly equal when the number of threads is modified.

Why does not the execution time decrease when the number of threads increase?

I am running this on a 32 core machine

Comment: to run different threads on different CPUs. the `attr` parameter must be properly set in the call(s) to `pthread_create()`

Comment: we cannot reproduce the problem, as the home-grown header file: `concurrent_map.h` contents are not posted.

Comment: in function: `FlowId_eq()` the identifier `false` is not declared anywhere.  This can be fixed by `include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: regarding: the function signature: `void *expirator(void *arg)`  The parameter `arg` is not used anywhere in the function, so the first line in the body should be: `(void)arg;`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  For `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gni11`.  The posted code (which is missing the contents of `concurrent_map.h)  results in 44 warnings and error messages from the compiler.

Comment: the function: `loop()` is being called in several places in the code, but never defined

Comment: regarding: `void **key_alloc = malloc(sizeof(void *) * (ENTRIES_PER_BUCKET));

                if (key_alloc != NULL)`   what about when it is NULL?

Comment: there are several calls to `malloc()`, but only one call to `free().  The result is a massive memory leak.  For every call to allocate memory from the 'heap' there must be a call to `free()`

Comment: regarding: `if (map_alloc == NULL)
    {
        return 0;`   in general, when everything is successful, then return 0, other wise suggest: `return -1;`

Comment: regarding the call to: `concurrent_map_put()` in function: expirator()`, the  actual function returns a 0 or 1 to indicate if it was successful or failed.  However the call to that function ignores the returned value, making the assumption that the call was successful.

Comment: regarding: `if (external_port != external)
        {
            error++;`  the variable `error` is being incremented but is never checked nor reported upon.

Comment: regarding; `concurrent_map_allocate(FlowId_eq, FlowId_hash, 65536, &(concurrent_map));` in function `main()`, the function:`concurrent_map_allocate() returns a 0 or a 1 to indicate if it was successful or not. However the call in `main()` ignores that success/failure indication,

Comment: there are LOTS more problems in the code, but the above comments should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: regarding: `#include <stdlib.h>`  Why include this header file twice?  Why include `linux/limits.h`?  how many of the other included header files are not used?  It is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used

Comment: @user3629249 thank you for the valuable feedback. Actually this code was not supposed to be a production ready code, it is just meant to understand the performance of the concurrent hash map design.

Also, the definition for the loop() method is there in the code, and you can remove the concurrent_map.h include directive and run it.

Comment: The OP posted this code to ask about the efficiency of the 'concurrent hash' functionality.  Before that can be answered, the code needs to cleanly compile.  The posted code does NOT compile.    Removing the `#include <concurrent_map.h>` header files results in several of the error and warning messages from the compiler.  Suggest, rather than saying to remove that header file, to rather, post the contents of that header file.

Comment: I see you modified the posted code.  And did not 'EDIT' those areas changed.  The original posted code did not contain a `loop()` function

Answer (score 0):

rand() is usually not suited for multi threaded execution. Instead use rand_r().

Also use linux time tool for timing the application.

Your workload generation imposes a huge overhead, and I assume it is the bottleneck here, not the concurrent hash map